# How to parse/split a string?

Tags: java, string, parsing, split

This is my string which is returned from DB,

```
"N,591;F\"Vendor Number\",86;F\"Vendor Name\",143;F\"Claim Number\",82;"
```

and stored in string columns,

I want to extract 'Vendor Number','Vendor Name' and 'Claim Number'..Any ideas how I can do that?
Thanks...

Comment: Split(";").Split(",")??

Comment: post your code u try?? try simple algorthim regex or some loop..

Comment: Yes please post your code. Also, what kind of database?

Comment: I tried Split(";") and I get array eg:' F\"Vendor Number\",86" ' and so on..How to extract just the string 'Vendor Number'?

Comment: What does `F` signify in your string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
String string = "N,591;F\"Vendor Number\",86;F\"Vendor Name\",143;F\"Claim Number\",82;";
String[] s = string.split("\"");
System.out.println(s[1]);
System.out.println(s[3]);
System.out.println(s[5]);
```

Output:

```
Vendor Number
Vendor Name
Claim Number
```

If the number of column labels is not known, choose every alternate index.

Answer (score 1):

package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class StringSplitTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("N,591;F\"Vendor Number\",86;F\"Vendor Name\",143;F\"Claim Number\",82;",";");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        StringTokenizer notRequired = new StringTokenizer((String) st.nextElement());
        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer((String) st.nextElement(),",");
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer((String) st.nextElement(),",");
        StringTokenizer st3 = new StringTokenizer((String) st.nextElement(),",");
        System.out.println(st1.nextElement()+ " = " + st1.nextElement());
        System.out.println(st2.nextElement()+ " = " + st2.nextElement());
        System.out.println(st3.nextElement()+ " = " + st3.nextElement());

}
```

}
}